# ExoPlayer2 Scaling

Tags: android, video, scale, exoplayer

I have an Activity that contains a FrameLayout where ExoPlayer takes place.
This activity support both orientations and video aspect ratio should be preserved.

According to `ExoPlayer` docs, for the `setResizeMode` we can have one of the following:

- RESIZE_MODE_FIT,
- RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH,
- RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_HEIGHT,
- RESIZE_MODE_FILL,
- RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM

In my case, since I don't know the video size nor the device orientation, I can have two scenarios:

- Video is **larger** than my Viewport, so I would like to have `RESIZE_MODE_FIT` to scale it down
- Video is **smaller** than my Viewport, so I would like to have `RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM` to scale it up.

But in the end I could not find a way to achieve this behavior.
If I set `RESIZE_MODE_FIT`, small videos does not fill my Viewport.
If I set `RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM`, large videos overflow the Viewport.

Thanks.